# ¿Cómo describir una "sensación de aventura"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

Estoy buscando una palabra o grupo de palabras que describa la sensación que uno tiene cuando está al borde de una aventura (léase tirarse en paracaídas o internarse intrépidamente en la selva).

Apreciaría evitar "adrenalina" ya que la he usado varias veces en el texto y no quiero repetirla. Tampoco me parece que sea la palabra más adecuada. Uno no "siente la adrenalina aumentando", la adrenalina es una hormona no un sentimiento, preferiría palabras que tengan que ver con sentimientos. Busco algo que amalgame

> **emoción/misterio/aventura/curiosidad/incertidumbre**

Comment: Tal vez sea una palabra muy jergal, pero a mí la palabra que más me viene a la cabeza es "**subidón**". No está en el DRAE, pero en España se usa muchísimo.

Comment: En efecto, se debe usar en España porque nunca la he escuchado :P ¿es usada para estos casos o para "otras cosas que suben" ?

Comment: Jeje qué pena. Se usa para indicar el sentimiento de "subida emocional" cuando por ejemplo estás en un concierto y el grupo toca su canción más famosa.

Comment: @fedorqui Entiendo, no sería exactamente la palabra que estoy buscando igual.

Comment: subidón tambien se usa para describir los efectos de las drogas con efectos estimulantes.

Answer (score 3):

No sé si amalgama todas, pero todas ellas provocan *anticipación*.

En la [teoría de Plutchik](http://kliquers.org/tutores/plutchik/), es una emoción de las ocho primarias y es la que nos compele a explorar.

Comment: Interesante, guillem. Considera añadir algún tipo de información adicional, pues el contenido actual es algo corto y ha enviado tu respuesta a la cola de revisión "low quality posts". Estoy seguro que Fundéu ha escrito algo al respecto, por ejemplo :)

Comment: Podría funcionar...habría que anticipar "ese algo" que es este conjunto de sentimientos.

Comment: @fedorqui por desgracia no he encontrado nada interesante en Fundéu, ¿sirve un renglón más para hacer la menos seca? Creo que debería haberla propuesto en un comentario.

Comment: @fedorqui Estoy seguro **de** que :) http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=seguro#5

Comment: @Gorpik ¡ay! Me lo apunto, pues también lo digo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Considera utilizar una frase que ilustre precisamente ese punto. Por ejemplo:

> De pronto me ahogué en un mar de sentimientos, las sensaciones que hervían en esta olas me abatían rápida y continuamente. A pesar de ser difícil distinguirlas, la calidez inconfundible de la curiosidad se alternaba con la frialdad casi sepulcral de la incertidumbre que culminó dejándome un sabor ceniciento en mi boca. Una vez que la marea de emociones relajó su dominio sobre mí, me preparé para enfrentar el misterio cuyo rastros de gusto todavía permanecían levemente en mi paladar.

Cuando te encuentres batallando con describir una mezcla de sensaciones o sentimientos, es válido recurrir a figuras literarias tales como [metáforas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Met%C3%A1fora). Cierra los ojos y busca cómo describirías esa conjunción de elementos, su interacción y las secuelas de cada parte en el personaje afectado. El resultado inicial puede que no sea tan coherente pero te da la pauta para trabajar sobre algo que caracterice a tu estilo de los demás y te guíe en predicamentos similares.

Answer (score 0):

Planteamiento:  "*Estoy buscando una palabra o grupo de palabras que describa la sensación que uno tiene cuando está al borde de una aventura*"

---

Aquí te dejo algunas palabras que puedan servir a tu cometido.

- agitación
- ajetreo
- alboroto
- alegría
- conmoción
- diversión
- escalofrío
- emoción
- entusiasmo
- epinefrina
- estremecimiento
- excitante
- excitación
- expectación
- ilusión
- nerviosismo
- precipitación
- prisa
- revuelo
- sensación
- subidón

Saludos. Diego M.